# jquery mouseenter and fadeTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want a div to be faded to opacity 1 when mouse enters, and to 0.5 when it leaves. This is my code:

```
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#header").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#header").fadeTo('fast', 1);
        });
        $("#header").mouseleave(function(){
            $("#header").fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });

    }


    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

        <div id="header">
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
            <p>blah blah...</p>
        </div>

</body>
```

I have a div in the body containing one h1 and one p. Nothing happens when I move the mouse over it. Is something wrong?

Comment: can you post your html as well?

Comment: @KyleWeller is it because I have a picture as background-image?

Comment: @KyleWeller I have added the html now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrong indentation hides a syntax error :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#header").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#header").fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $("#header").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#header").fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
}); // <= missing parenthesis
```

Other than that, [it works](http://jsbin.com/awitob/3/edit). Be careful that 0.5 isn't really transparent for all color combinations.

Comment: Did you try the fiddle I linked to ? It perfectly works. Click the "run with js" button.

Comment: is it because I have a image as ackground-image?

Comment: No error in [the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) ? If the image is in the header, it should have its opacity changed. Try with 0.1 instead of 0.5 to better see it.

Comment: I gave you a link in the last comment. You really should learn to use the developer tools of your browser (Firefox or Chrome) before coding more javascript. It's almost impossible to do anything complex without that.

Answer (score 0):

How about css?

```
#header {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
#header:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Just make sure to add all the css vendor prefixes. This is better than using jQuery IMO. If browser doesn't support `transition` or `opacity` it's no big deal, that's what "graceful degradation" is all about.

Comment: that works! thanks but I still dont undestand why it doesnt work with my js code...